# Stored Procedure Return Unique Identifier

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a question which has been frustrating me and I have googled and googled and can't find what I want.

I have this SQL Server stored procedure, which works great and returns the unique identifier:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mcd_AddLogin]
   @UserName         nvarchar(256),
   @Password         nvarchar(256),
   @UID              uniqueidentifier OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   IF( @UID IS NULL )
        SELECT @UID = NEWID()
   ELSE
   BEGIN
       IF( EXISTS( SELECT [USERNAME] FROM dbo.LoginPassing_Active) )
          RETURN -1
   END

Declare @Active bit
Declare @Exp_Date datetime
Set @Active = 1
Set @Exp_Date =  DATEADD(mi, 1, GETDATE())

INSERT dbo.LoginPassing ([USERNAME], [PASSWORD], [ACTIVE], [EXP_DATE], [UID])
VALUES (@UserName, @Password, @Active, @Exp_Date, @Uid)

RETURN 0
END
```

I am trying to use this in and ASP.NET application, and am getting the following error:

> *Procedure or function 'mcd_AddLogin' expects parameter '@UID', which was not supplied.*

Below is the code in my ASP.Net application, can anyone help me solve what is going wrong, I'm sure its really simple and I have just missed a trick:

```
    Dim conSQL As New SqlConnection
    conSQL.ConnectionString = My.Settings.conSQL
    conSQL.Open()

    Dim comSQL As New SqlCommand

    comSQL.Connection = conSQL
    comSQL.CommandText = "mcd_AddLogin"
    comSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    comSQL.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "username"
    comSQL.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "password"

    comSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
    litAD.Text = comSQL.Parameters("@UID").Value
```

Appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: In your code, it looks like you're executing the stored procedure, comSQL.ExecuteNonQuery(), before you're adding the parameter on the next line.

Comment: No this is how you get the output value... this is not adding a parameter, it is reading it. Thanks Steve.

Comment: That's true, but you have to add it before execution as well - taking note to set it's Direction property accordingly as well. At the moment you're problem is that the output parameter is not even in the parameters collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was googling the wrong thing - I wanted OUTPUT parameters, I solved the problem with my code below:

```
    comSQL.Connection = conSQL
    comSQL.CommandText = "mcd_AddLogin"
    comSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    comSQL.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "spearce"
    comSQL.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "kintikai"
    comSQL.Parameters.Add("@UID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)
    comSQL.Parameters("@UID").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    comSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
    litAD.Text = comSQL.Parameters("@UID").Value
```

Thanks for your help anyways.

Answer (score 6):

In *stored procedure* you have **output** parameter, then you must provide that parameter and after SP execution you can get output value from parameter.

Try this:

```
comSQL.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "password"
comSQL.Parameters.Add("@UID", SqlDbType.Int)
comSQL.Parameters("@UID").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
comSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
litAD.Text = comSQL.Parameters("@UID").Value
```

Comment: I just worked out my own problem using the below, same as yours. Thanks for being so quick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to spacefiy the  `Parameter Direction` and pass it before calling `ExecuteNonQuery()`

eg

```
myParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
```

Please read more about [Input and Output Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x02y99%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)